# Find max and min from a object in javascript only

Tags: javascript

Hi I have an array like below....

```
dataArray(7)[
{dataIndex: 0, specialEventID: 65268}
1
:
{dataIndex: 1, specialEventID: 65268}
2
:
{dataIndex: 1, specialEventID: 65271}
3
:
{dataIndex: 1, specialEventID: 65272}
4
:
{dataIndex: 2, specialEventID: 65270}
5
:
{dataIndex: 5, specialEventID: 65269}
6
:
{dataIndex: 6, specialEventID: 65269}
]
```

Now I want max and min index of every specialEventID
Like 65268['max':1, 'min':0]

```
65271['max':1, 'min':1] //because only one object for 65271
 65272['max':1, 'min':1] //because only one object for 65272
 65270['max':2, 'min':2]//because only one object for 65270
 65270['max':5, 'min':6]
```

Can anyone please help me to find the max and min index like above?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. That would really helps us to figure out the issue with your code. Thanks!

Comment: Hi @palasH, I could not figure out how shall I proceed, but expected result would be 65271['max':1, 'min':1] //because only one object for 65271
 65272['max':1, 'min':1] //because only one object for 65272
 65270['max':2, 'min':2]//because only one object for 65270
 65270['max':5, 'min':6]

Comment: I need the first and last occurrence of a particular specialEventID in a array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an object for the result, where `specialEventID` acts as key and an object for min and max values.

```js
var data = [{ dataIndex: 0, specialEventID: 65268 }, { dataIndex: 1, specialEventID: 65268 }, { dataIndex: 1, specialEventID: 65271 }, { dataIndex: 1, specialEventID: 65272 }, { dataIndex: 2, specialEventID: 65270 }, { dataIndex: 5, specialEventID: 65269 }, { dataIndex: 6, specialEventID: 65269 }],
    result = {};

data.forEach(function (o) {
    if (!result[o.specialEventID]) {
        result[o.specialEventID] = { min: o.dataIndex, max: o.dataIndex };
        return;
    }
    if (result[o.specialEventID].min > o.dataIndex) {
        result[o.specialEventID].min = o.dataIndex;
        return;
    }
    if (result[o.specialEventID].max < o.dataIndex) {
        result[o.specialEventID].max = o.dataIndex;
    }
});
    
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Hi @Nina Scholz, Thanks you. it's working perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dataArray = [
{dataIndex: 0, specialEventID: 65268},
{dataIndex: 1, specialEventID: 65268},
{dataIndex: 1, specialEventID: 65271},
{dataIndex: 1, specialEventID: 65272},
{dataIndex: 2, specialEventID: 65270},
{dataIndex: 5, specialEventID: 65269},
{dataIndex: 6, specialEventID: 65269}
];

 
const ret = dataArray.reduce((a,v) => { 
  var k = v.specialEventID;
  a[k] = a[k] ? 
    { min: Math.min(a[k].max, v. dataIndex), 
      max: Math.max(a[k].max, v. dataIndex) } :
    { min: v.dataIndex, max: v.dataIndex};
  return a;
}, {});

console.log(ret);
```